# Mysql connections in php safe usage without overloading

Tags: php, mysql

I actually don't have an issue but I have a question.
For example I have a php file index.php inner code:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE approved=1 ORDER BY date ASC LIMIT 100"; 
$result = mysqli_query($conn,$query);
$i=1;
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
  {
  echo $i++ .".";
  echo "<a href='" .$row['ID'] .  "' style='text-decoration:none'> ". $row['Name'] . " </a> ";
  echo $row['age'];
  echo "<br>";
  }
mysqli_close($conn);
```

In reality there is more info taken from database, and the page is visited lats say 99999 times a day , will it overload site? Should I use some other method doing that?
What if 200 people viewing the page at the same time , and lats say there are 500 results?

The main question is , how to NOT overload the mysql server with many visitors opening the same page at the same time?

Answer (score 1):

How dynamic is the data and how up to date does it need to be?

Where I'm going is that neither of the above is a problem then you can always cache the result in a text file and display it instead of making the call to the server you're afraid to overload.

You can use a cron job to update the file every 5 minutes, or what ever interval you think is appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

Even a simple web server will be able to execute that page 100.000 times a day, provided visitors are evenly spread. But an actual website will be far more complex. It will probably hold session information and it may execute dozens or even hundreds of queries per page view.

To manage that load, you use a dedicated host instead of shared hosting. You can cache query results in memcache. Later, you can expand server memory and processing power to have more caching space and support more simultaneous requests. Then you use multiple webservers in a cluster and have a load balancer. You can separate your database server from the webserver, and you may even have separate memcache server(s). In the end there is a limit to what your hardware can do and it boils down to adding more hardware.

Point is, if those 10 lines of code are all you have now, don't worry about it yet. As your site and its visitor count grows, you will also gain knowledge about how to increase performance a bit at the time.

Comment: The website I work on is a webshop. It processes 10.000 orders per day on average days, so the number of page views is a multitude of that. The whole thing runs on 6 webservers and 8 separate database servers. But then again, it has complex pages, uses hundreds of tables and also can use hundreds of queries per page view (although most of them are mem cached). You can't just say that 10 tables will overload the server. It doesn't work that way. But again, you don't have to worry about that yet. You won't have 100.000 visitors overnight.

Comment: Well actually I don't have any problems and the code is totally different, i just want to know if its the right way using query to show results. In reality I'm talking about Websites top listing script.

Comment: @GolezTrol *and a help* i have a domain and i planed to create 8 separate database servers do i need to create separate database in same domain or some other new domain???

Comment: @sanojlawrence We have them in the same domain. But maybe you would better ask this as an actual question on ServerFault than to trust just my single comment. :) I must admit I'm not the master brain that invented the entire setup we have.